# What is latest proven-that-works combination of Liferay and Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, liferay

I just tried Wicket 1.5.6 and Liferay 6.1.0 combination and that is not working out of the box, at least not for me.

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-examples-as-portlets.html

says that examples.war should work without any problem, but for me it tells after deploy that

```
11:53:17,096 ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.IllegalStateException: filter path was not configured
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:164)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:241)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
```

and won't work. Do you know

a) solution to this error

b) which combination of these two works out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know still what was that prevented that combination of running, but I tested again with Wicket 1.5.6 and Liferay 6.0.6 and everything worked like charm.

On my side that is ok, because the used Liferay version is on minor importance for me.