# Does Liferay 6.2 support apache wicket?

Tags: liferay, wicket, liferay-6, wicket-1.5

I started to read about wicket integration with liferay. I found very old information that wicket portlet is no longer supported, but wicket version 1.5.6 works fine with [liferay 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833462/what-is-latest-proven-that-works-combination-of-liferay-and-wicket). What about Liferay 6.2?

Answer (score 2):

Just yesterday a user from the community created a Pull Request to fix the support for Liferay: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/pull/476.

The Pull Request is for WicketStuff 7.x though. You are very welcome to port the fixes to wicket-6.x branch and we will add them for WicketStuff 6.23.0.

WicketStuff 1.5.x is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Wicket version 6.x, 7.x and 8.x supports JSR286 portlets.

Please see the following wiki of how to use the apache wicket portlet bridge.

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Portlet